# watching the created query in solrnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr, solrnet

I'm using solrnet in a MVC3 application. Now I run into some errors. For finding the reason it would be very helpful to print out the created "solr-request-url".
is there a possibility to give out the created query/the full URL.

I create my Query on following way:

```
var result = solr.Query(...);
```

thanks a lot for your answers!

solr-request-url means: `http://localhost:9983/solr/select/?q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also see the URL (and the exception stack trace, if any) in the Solr log.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, set up a [ISolrConnection](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/ISolrConnection.cs) decorator. See [LoggingConnection](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SampleSolrApp/LoggingConnection.cs) in the sample 
app for reference.

Comment: var connection = new SolrConnection(solrURL); 
   
   var loggingConnection = new LoggingConnection(connection); 
   
   Startup.Init<Product>(loggingConnection);